# Trying to get all the text from an external webpage with JS (JSON in an array)

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying some things with JS to get all smartphones brands. I found this API : [GSMArena API](https://gsmarena-api.herokuapp.com/brands)

As you can see, the content is on an array, and I don't know how to get informations in this case.

I thought about different things. I would like to take all the text from URL, remove the array symbols as a string, and then, just take informations with parsing. That's certainly not the best idea possible.

I tried several things to do that, and none are working (using fetch, request, axios ...) :

```js
var getJSON = function (url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  xhr.responseType = "json";
  xhr.onload = function () {
    var status = xhr.status;
    if (status === 200) {
      callback(null, xhr.response);
    } else {
      callback(status, xhr.response);
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
};

getJSON("https://gsmarena-api.herokuapp.com/brands", function (err, data) {
  if (err !== null) {
    alert("Something went wrong: " + err);
  } else {
    console.log(data)
  }
});
```

If you could help me with what I'm trying to, or if you have another idea, that would help a lot ! Thanks :D

Comment: Does it needs to be with XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: I never used this kind of thing, but I can try it, as you want !

Comment: Can you explain how do you wanna take the text? Its just simple 'foreach' will solve the issue.

Comment: Basically, my problem is not about the use of text, it's just having the text in a way. I used axios and others, and it doesn't give anything.

But basically, I would like to have the text in a string or a file.